# Create a folder for every file within a directory and move file into corresponding folder

Tags: batch, cmd.exe, script

I have a set of files distributed throughout a directory that need to be moved into folders with equivalent titles, in place.

```
Original Structure:
Folder A
 A1
  Dog.pdf
 A2
  Cat.tif

Desired structure:
Folder A
 A1
  Dog
   Dog.pdf
 A2
  Cat
   Cat.tif
```

I've tried making this script recursive so it applies to the entire directory, but it ends up nesting the files in infinite folders:

```
@echo & Title %~n0
cd /D "%~dp0"
for /r %%i in (*) do (
 if not "%%~DPni" == "%~DPn0" (
  md "%%~DPni" && move "%%~i" "%%~DPni"
 )
)
```

Is there a way for it to act on a directory and all its subfolders, creating a folder wherever the file is and moving that file into the folder?

Comment: If **PowerShell** is an option, this will do the trick: `(gci -af -s) | %{ $Dest = md (Join-Path $_.DirectoryName $_.BaseName) ; $_ | Move -Destination $Dest.FullName }
`

Comment: This solution worked perfectly.